# Args invalid syntax python

Tags: python, syntax, config, args

Why is the invalid syntax and how can I actually fix this? I have

```
import sys
import yaml
import threading
import argparse
from math import pi
```

And later on I have

```
with args.config as f:
    config - yaml.load(f)
```

However every time I try to run it it throws up the error that args is invalid syntax. Please tell me, what can I do?

Comment: Maybe you meant `config = yaml.load(f)`?

Comment: what is `args` from 'with args.config as f:` statement??

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the traceback you get for "invalid syntax"?

Answer (score 0):

like @Dani says:
change:

```
with args.config as f:
    config - yaml.load(f)
```

to

```
with args.config as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
```

Comment: @xnx I suspect (and just guessing until the OP bothers clarifying) that "invalid syntax" is something being thrown from the `yaml` library... `config - yaml.load(f)` isn't a `SyntaxError` (but definitely not what's intended though)...